# Undetected chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I tried launching youtube using undetected chromedriver with this code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = uc.Chrome(headless=True)
    driver.get("https://youtube.com")
```

But got this error:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Chrome.__del__ at 0x00000271674DBEC0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 843, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 798, in quit   
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Tried to launch youtube

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with `undetected_chromedriver` module itself. I see an [Open PR](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/pull/1339) for fixing this issue.

If you want to get around this sooner, you can probably modify the init file add a try-except block around `time.sleep(0.1)` similar to what's done in [this commit](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/pull/1339/files)

`C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py`

```
try:
    time.sleep(0.1)
except OSError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the latest version of selenium is causing issues for undetected_chromedriver, try to install older version of selenium